# According to doctors name (dropdown) and date selected ,change timeslot dropdown using AJAX in django

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax, date

```
//This is my book_appoint.html
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
 <div class="wrapper"> 
<div class="register-page">
 <div class="register-container"> 
<form id="appointment-form" role="form" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

<!-- SECTION TITLE -->
      <div class="section-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
           <h2>Book Appointment</h2>
      </div>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input name="patient_name" value="{{request.user}}" hidden> 
      <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.8s">
           

           <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <label for="qualification">Doctor Name</label>
                {{ form.doctor_name }}
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <label for="specialist"> Date</label>
                {{ form.date }}
           </div>
           

           <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <label for="location">Time slot </label>
                {{ form.time_slot }}   // want to apply ajax to select available slot only
           </div>
           

           <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <label for="description"> Description</label>
                {{ form.description }}
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="submitButton" id="cf-submit" name="submit">Submit Button</button>
           </div>
      </div>
</form>
</div> </div> </div>

</html>

//This is my view file:

def book_appointment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookAppointmentForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            patient_name = request.POST.get('patient_name')
            patient = form.save(commit=False)
            patient.patient_name = User.objects.get(username=patient_name)



            
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'appointment booked Successfully')
            return redirect(homepage)
        else:
            form = BookAppointmentForm()
            messages.error(request, 'Please Enter valid Request ')
            print(form)
            return render(request, 'book_appointment.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = BookAppointmentForm()
        return render(request, 'book_appointment.html', {'form': form})

//Here is my models:

class BookAppointment(models.Model):
    TIME_SLOT = (
        (0, '09:00 - 10:00'),
        (1, '10:00 - 11:00'),
        (2, '11:00 - 12:00'),
        (3, '12:00 - 13:00'),
        (4, '13:00 - 14:00'),
        (5, '14:00 - 15:00'),
        (6, '15:00 - 16:00'),
        (7, '16:00 - 17:00'),
        (8, '17:00 - 18:00'),
    
    )
    doctor_name=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="doctor_name")
    patient_name=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="patient_name")
    description=models.TextField(blank = True)
    date=models.DateField(help_text="DD-MM-YYYY")
    time_slot= models.IntegerField(choices=TIME_SLOT)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('date', 'time_slot')
        unique_together = (
            ('doctor_name', 'date', 'time_slot'),  

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {}. Patient: {}'.format(self.date, self.time_slot, self.doctor_name, self.patient_name)
```

I have already post this form and it store values simple in database.But I have not used Ajax , which I want to apply here, when user select particular doctor name from dropdown and after that user select dates from calendar, through Ajax it should be able to select available Timeslots, and also disable timeslots which are already booked(unavailable).

Comment: and where is your Ajax code?

Comment: @Jonas Its in Static>js>main.js, But for this solution I have not used any logic yet as I am confuse that do I need to apply Ajax when doctors name is selected or When date is selected?